# How to group by dict values and store into list in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pandas

I have a dictionary, I want to make n number of list based on the unique values in dictionary value.

For example:

```
dic={
"allenp":10,"amber.ebow@enron.com":13,"amelia.alland@enron.com":13,"andrea.ring@enron.com":15,"andy.zipper@enron.com":9,"anne.bike@enron.com":10,"anne.koehler@enron.com":4,"arnold-j":9,"barbara.gray@enron.com":6,"barton.clark@enron.com":9,"bass-e":6,"gary.lamphier@enron.com":6,"gay-r":13,"gerald.nemec@enron.com":12}
```

I want to convert this into Expected Output,

```
[['anne.koehler@enron.com'], ['gary.lamphier@enron.com', 'bass-e', 'barbara.gray@enron.com'], ['arnold-j', 'barton.clark@enron.com', 'andy.zipper@enron.com'], ['allenp', 'anne.bike@enron.com'], ['gerald.nemec@enron.com'], ['amelia.alland@enron.com', 'gay-r', 'amber.ebow@enron.com'], ['andrea.ring@enron.com']]
```

How to do this in Javascript?

I'm new to javascript.

If I need to solve this problem in python I would do like below,

```
df= pd.DataFrame(dic.items())
x=[]
[x.append(v[0].values.tolist()) for u,v in df.groupby([1])]
print x
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to group by values in one object and then `Object.values` on that object.

```js
const obj ={"allenp":10,"amber.ebow@enron.com":13,"amelia.alland@enron.com":13,"andrea.ring@enron.com":15,"andy.zipper@enron.com":9,"anne.bike@enron.com":10,"anne.koehler@enron.com":4,"arnold-j":9,"barbara.gray@enron.com":6,"barton.clark@enron.com":9,"bass-e":6,"gary.lamphier@enron.com":6,"gay-r":13,"gerald.nemec@enron.com":12}

const arr = Object.entries(obj)
.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  if(!r[v]) r[v] = [];
  r[v].push(k);
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(arr))
```

You could also use `for...of` loop to add to object and then `Object.values` to get an array.

```js
const obj ={"allenp":10,"amber.ebow@enron.com":13,"amelia.alland@enron.com":13,"andrea.ring@enron.com":15,"andy.zipper@enron.com":9,"anne.bike@enron.com":10,"anne.koehler@enron.com":4,"arnold-j":9,"barbara.gray@enron.com":6,"barton.clark@enron.com":9,"bass-e":6,"gary.lamphier@enron.com":6,"gay-r":13,"gerald.nemec@enron.com":12}

const result = {}
for([k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) (result[v] = (result[v] || [])).push(k)
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

If you want keys only:

```
Object.entries(obj) === ["allenp", "amber.ebow@enron.com", "amelia.alland@enron.com", "andrea.ring@enron.com"]... etc
```

If you want values only:

```
Object.values(obj) === [10, 13, 13, 15, 9, 10]...etc
```

If you want values AND keys in a multidimensional array:

```
Object.entries(obj) === [["allenp", 10], ["amber.ebow@enron.com", 13], ["amelia.alland@enron.com", 13]] ...etc
```